# Masks on live preview on camera2Api?

Tags: android

i implemented my camera2 api taking picture and all. But now i need to implement the face detection to that camera and add snapchat like masks on the face after face is detected. please find me solution or ideas how to implemented it using Camera2APi Not camera1

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement your own algorithm on filters (or masks, if you prefer). Currently camera2 api supports built-in face recognition, which may or may not be suited for your needs. In any case, there is no *simple* solution.

Below is the simple code of returning the faces on the camera preview callback

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mPhotoCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
//more code...
private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES); // will return an array of faces Face[]
               //more code....
                break;
            }
//more code...
}
```

Comment: I have seen examples like this which are done in  camera 1 https://github.com/hardik-trivedi/FaceFilter. I thought there is implementation metholody for camera 2 api

Comment: The example in your link implements its own method on overlaying filters (see GraphicOverlay.java). The example also obtains an instance of Face in a similar fashion as the code snippet I provided would do.